# How to get the reverse association field, especially with intermediate tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I would like to know how to get the reverse association field, given a field on a model. For example, if a `User` model has a foreign key (i.e., `belongs_to`) to the `Role` model and the `Role` model has the appropriate `has_many` association to the `User` model, then AFAIK, setting `User.role` is the same as adding the user to `Role.users`. I'm trying to figure out how to discover programmatically that `Role.users` is the reverse relation of `User.role`.

I know how to get ActiveRecord associations using a model's reflections. In my given example, `User.reflections['role']` will yield the `belongs_to` association, and `Role.reflections['users']` will yield the `has_many` reflection on the "other side". I want to know how to figure out programmatically that `Role.users` is the reverse association of `User.role`, and vice-versa. In Django this is usually done by inspecting the `related_name` property.

Right now I am inspecting reflections, and determining if a reflection is on the other side by using the `foreign_key` property of the reflection objects. For example, both `User.reflections['role'].foreign_key` and `Role.reflections['users'].foreign_key` will return `role_id`.

However, this doesn't work for some associations, like some many-to-many, or `:through` associations. Some other methods I've tried don't work if a model has multiple associations to the same model.

How can I figure out which reflection/field on the other model corresponds to a given field on a particular model?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `User.reflections['role'].inverse_of`. For doing it works with `:through` associations - you need to explicit point `inverse_of` on both models. For example

```rb
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tag_connections, inverse_of: :tag, source: :post
  has_many :posts, through: :tag_connections, inverse_of: :tags
end

class TagConnection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :post
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tag_connections, inverse_of: :post
  has_many :tags, inverse_of: :posts
end
```

Comment: I think you might need explicit `:inverse_of` for even normal `belongs_to`/`has_many` associations, because in my environment, `User.reflections['role'].inverse_of` returns `nil`.

Comment: It will be return ```nil``` if you haven't properly setted ```inverse_of``` setting

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. It sucks because so many rails apps rely on ActiveRecord to make that association for them, but then in reflections it would be nice to programmatically get to the "other side". I also figured out that for HABTM, comparing the other model's reflections to see which one's `association_foreign_key` matches the source reflection's `foreign_key` is useful.